# AngularJS ui-grid does not update select all state when data changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ui-grid

I have a ui-grid with multi-select enabled. Everything works fine, except when the data changes, the "select" column in the header does not properly show the state of the grid. I've created a [simple example in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MTXR8Q?p=preview) that illustrates the issue. To reproduce, simply click on the select header button.

[image: All rows selected]

Then hit the "Add Data" button.

[image: Header does not match grid state]

Notice that the header still shows the check mark, but the newly added row is not checked.

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.swapData = function() {
    if ($scope.gridOpts.data === data1) {
      $scope.gridOpts.data = data2;
      $scope.gridOpts.columnDefs = columnDefs2;
    }
    else {
      $scope.gridOpts.data = data1;
      $scope.gridOpts.columnDefs = columnDefs1;
    }
  };

  $scope.addData = function() {
    var n = $scope.gridOpts.data.length + 1;
    $scope.gridOpts.data.push({
                "firstName": "New " + n,
                "lastName": "Person " + n,
                "company": "abc",
                "employed": true,
                "gender": "male"
              });
  };

  $scope.removeFirstRow = function() {
    //if($scope.gridOpts.data.length > 0){
       $scope.gridOpts.data.splice(0,1);
    //}
  };

  $scope.reset = function () {
    data1 = angular.copy(origdata1);
    data2 = angular.copy(origdata2);

    $scope.gridOpts.data = data1;
    $scope.gridOpts.columnDefs = columnDefs1;
  }

  var columnDefs1 = [
    { name: 'firstName' },
    { name: 'lastName' },
    { name: 'company' },
    { name: 'gender' }
  ];

  var data1 = [
    {
      "firstName": "Cox",
      "lastName": "Carney",
      "company": "Enormo",
      "gender": "male"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Lorraine",
      "lastName": "Wise",
      "company": "Comveyer",
      "gender": "female"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Nancy",
      "lastName": "Waters",
      "company": "Fuelton",
      "gender": "female"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Misty",
      "lastName": "Oneill",
      "company": "Letpro",
      "gender": "female"
    }
  ];

  var origdata1 = angular.copy(data1);

  var columnDefs2 = [
    { name: 'firstName' },
    { name: 'lastName' },
    { name: 'company' },
    { name: 'employed' }
  ];

  var data2 = [
    {
      "firstName": "Waters",
      "lastName": "Shepherd",
      "company": "Kongene",
      "employed": true
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Hopper",
      "lastName": "Zamora",
      "company": "Acium",
      "employed": true
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Marcy",
      "lastName": "Mclean",
      "company": "Zomboid",
      "employed": true
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Tania",
      "lastName": "Cruz",
      "company": "Marqet",
      "employed": true
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Kramer",
      "lastName": "Cline",
      "company": "Parleynet",
      "employed": false
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Bond",
      "lastName": "Pickett",
      "company": "Brainquil",
      "employed": false
    }
  ];

  var origdata2 = angular.copy(data2);

  $scope.gridOpts = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs1,
    data: data1,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableSelectAll: true,
    selectionRowHeaderWidth: 35
  };

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue please refer this: http://plnkr.co/edit/lJsWof?p=preview

where this is point of emphasis

```
$scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
```

Steps for checked or unchecked all the rows

1. get the object of grid

   ```
   $scope.gridOpts.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) 
   {
       $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
   };
   ```
2. call theire methods to clear rows

   ```
   $scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows()
   ```

please refer this http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.selection.api:PublicApi

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is not a viable solution. Plunker is just a very simple demonstration of the issue. In my actual code, I have elements being added and subtracted based on input from the user. I do not want to clear what has been previously selected, I want the ui-grid to be smart enough to recognize that all the rows are no longer selected. It will do this if you manually click on a row. For example, if you click on the "Add Data" button, a new row is added to the grid, but the header check is still selected.